# Matrix diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra

Does any one have any idea how to diagonalize the following matrix:
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a & 0 \\
a & 0 & b \\
0 & b & c
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

The solution with $c=0$, $a$ and $b$ non-zero is easy, but i need to find with a non-zero $c$. I tried with Mathematica but it didn't give any answer. I also tried to find one eigenvalue of the matrix by inspection, so that I could find the other two by calculating the roots of a polynomial of degree 2.

Comment: Is there something wrong with just solving the characteristic equation?

Comment: Thanks Hunter!!

JeffDror- I get a polynomial of degree 3. And I don't know how to find the roots of a polynomial of degree 3. One method that comes to my mind is find a eigenvalue by just looking at the matrix and then factorize this polynomial of degree 3 in one of degree one and another of degree 2.

Unfortunately i can't guess an eigenvalue just by looking to the matrix.

Comment: There's not going to be any simple formula for this.  Any formula will involve cube roots of expressions which in turn involve square roots of sixth degree polynomials.  (It will also involve cube roots of unity, so I hope you're working over a field where these exist!)

Comment: If you need $c \neq 0$, you can WLOG set $c=1$ and scale the other parameters accordingly.

Comment: If you can, consider expanding the solution in $c$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you typed it into Mathematica wrong, I get

```
A = {{0, a, 0}, {a, 0, b}, {0, b, c}};
{B, L} = {DiagonalMatrix@#1, Transpose@#2} & @@ Eigensystem[A];
Chop[A.L - L.B /. {a -> 1.2, b -> 3.4 + I, c -> 5.3 - I}]

(*Out: {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}} *)
```

If you know what $a,b,c$ are and they're parametrizable in terms of some underlying physical property, you may find it enlightening to plot the eigenvalues as a function of that reduced-dimensional property. $L$ and $B$ have closed forms, but they're somewhat long.

Comment: Where did you get those values of a,b,c?

Comment: I just made them up randomly as a numerical check of the symbolic result. If you execute `L` or `B` without substituting numbers in, it'll give you the symbolic matrices in terms of `Root` objects. To convert to radicals, apply `ToRadicals`.

Comment: Oh okay. My understanding was that the OP was hoping for a general solution for any $a,b,c$, which I don't think exists.

Comment: It exists, you just execute $L$ and $B$ to see what they are. They're long, which is why I didn't include the outputs.

Comment: For example, the diagonal entries of the diagonalized version of the matrix becomes `{Root[a^2 c + (-a^2 - b^2) #1 - c #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1], 
 Root[a^2 c + (-a^2 - b^2) #1 - c #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2], 
 Root[a^2 c + (-a^2 - b^2) #1 - c #1^2 + #1^3 &, 3]}`, which is the general solution for any $a,b,c$.

Comment: Applying `ToRadicals` gives the result in terms of square and cube roots. For example, the first eigenvalue is `c/3 - (2^(1/3) (-3 a^2 - 3 b^2 - c^2))/(
 3 (-18 a^2 c + 9 b^2 c + 2 c^3 + Sqrt[
    4 (-3 a^2 - 3 b^2 - c^2)^3 + (-18 a^2 c + 9 b^2 c + 2 c^3)^2])^(
  1/3)) + (-18 a^2 c + 9 b^2 c + 2 c^3 + Sqrt[
   4 (-3 a^2 - 3 b^2 - c^2)^3 + (-18 a^2 c + 9 b^2 c + 2 c^3)^2])^(
 1/3)/(3 2^(1/3))`.

Comment: Oh very nice. I got your result above earlier (with the Roots), but I didn't understand that it was already a closed form solution.